# Test Selection Sort Using Driver Program in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, testing

Good evening all, I have a program here that uses selection sort to sort an array alphabetically. I am attempting to test the selection sort using a driver program.

I've been googling all day and found some ways to test if the array is in ascending value using numbers but having lots of difficulty with alphabetical.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated! Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void selectionSort(string[], int);

void displayArray(string[], int);



int main()
{
const int SIZE = 20;

string name[SIZE] =

{"Collins, Bill", "Smith, Bart", "Michalski, Joe", "Griffin, Jim", "Sanchez, Manny", "Rubin, Sarah", 
"Taylor, Tyrone", "Johnson, Jill", "Allison, Jeff", "Moreno, Juan", "Wolfe, Bill", "Whitman, Jean", "Moretti, Bella", 
"Wu, Hong", "Patel, Renee", "Harrison, Rose", "Smith, Cathy", "Conroy, Pat", "Kelly, Sean", "Holland, Beth"};

selectionSort(name, SIZE);

displayArray(name, SIZE);

return 0;
}



// use selection sort to arrange  values in a string array in ascending order                                                       
void selectionSort(string array[], int size)
{
int startScan, minIndex;

string minValue;

for (int startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
{
    minIndex = startScan;

    minValue = array[startScan];

    for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
    {
        if(array[index] < minValue)
        {
            minValue = array[index];

            minIndex = index;
        }
    }
    array[minIndex] = array[startScan];

    array[startScan] = minValue;
}
}



// display all values in the array  
void displayArray(string name[], int size)
{
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cout << name[i] << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: You're going to need a string comparison function. Hint: For each character, if that character in the two strings are different, return. If the two characters are the same, compare the next two characters.

Comment: I don't get it, your code outputs all the names in the proper order: https://onlinegdb.com/BJunWdhqG

Comment: You can probably just use memcmp with a maximum length. Since `,`, space, and zero are less than alphanumeric characters, the compare will work.